# React - Separating app into multiple git repos

Tags: git, reactjs, routes, components, react-router

I wanted to get your input on a project I'm working on.
I have my main React App repo. From there my plan is to have a Component A repo and a Component B Repo. Then I would like to run my main App and if I load a certain route (/componentA) the component would be pulled in from the Component A git repo. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least as far as tracking change history goes, you can use git submodules per the subcomponent routes you want to develop, but for production they will need to be bundled together from the root into a single app that can have bundle splitting integrated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for you.

https://lernajs.io/

lerna will enable you to have multiple repos talk to each other, and easily update one, to reflect on all the repos that uses it.

> Splitting up large codebases into separate independently versioned packages is extremely useful for code sharing. However, making changes across many repositories is messy and difficult to track, and testing across repositories gets complicated really fast.
>
> To solve these (and many other) problems, some projects will organize their codebases into multi-package repositories. Projects like Babel, React, Angular, Ember, Meteor, Jest, and many others develop all of their packages within a single repository.
>
> Lerna is a tool that optimizes the workflow around managing multi-package repositories with git and npm.

jump to the get started to see how it works, I've started using it for our large code base, and its doing beautiful so far

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad Bamieh. I'll see if this will wok for me.

Comment: Lerna doesnt support Multiple CRA Apps.

Comment: @uzu can you elaborate?